# Long-term parking at Karlovy Vary airport (KLV)

Tags: airports, automobiles, czech-republic

I'm planning to travel to Moscow soon and it will be convenient for me to fly from Karlovy Vary in the Czech Republic.

It's written [here](https://www.airport-k-vary.cz/en/parking/) on the airport website that parking is free but the car parks are not supervised. I will be travelling for two weeks. Is it safe to leave the car for this time at the airport? If not, are there recommended parking areas in the city of Karlovy Vary which are supervised and reasonably priced for two weeks?